# The best method to redirect if user acess from Android devices?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all Android visitors to a specific page, I have tried something like this with php but I am not sure of my method, I want it to be 100% working for all the Android devices possible. What do you think, is it safe to go like this?

```
<?php
$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

if(strpos($user_agent, "Android") == TRUE)
header("Location: /savoir/android");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never be 100% sure if all traffic from an Android device will be redirected. But I think this will cover almost everyting.

There is a great list of user-agents here: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_system_name/android/